# Генерация графиков в цикле в Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, визуализация

Есть [датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JAacwyDEUbX0rQcZCQJYTDYp28Ctz16K/view?usp=sharing). Нужно построить "ящики с усами" для данных из всех его столбцов. Названия столбцов отличаются друг от друга числом по нарастающей: 'feature_1', 'feature_2'  и т.д. Код почему-то загоняет все 5 столбцов в один график, а не генерирует 5 графиков.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
result = pd.read_csv('result.csv', encoding='utf-8') 

for i in range (1, 6):
    n = "feature_" + str(i)
    plt.title("Распределение " + n)
    plt.boxplot(result[n])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы код генерировал в цикле все 5 графиков по отдельности, а не перемешивал все данные в один график.

Comment: по отдельности как? на одном полотне несколько отдельных графиков, или несколько отдельных полотен (файлов) с графиками?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы каждый график был в отдельной картинке, нужно делать перед каждым графиком так:

```
plt.figure() # тут можно ещё `figsize=(размерX,размерY)` задать
```

Можно ещё сделать графики в несколько колонок для экономии места, тогда нужно использовать `plt.subplots`, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728991/8324991).

Comment: зачем figure каждый раз? ax генерировать новые и фсе

Comment: @strawdog Ну я так издревле делаю. Генерировать `ax` будет проще/правильнее?

Comment: Если нужно несколько графиков на одной фигуре, то конечно ax генерировать проще, тем более, что работа через ax - это ооп, а через figure - функционал. сами разработчики матплотлиб советуют работать с ооп.